# CSS wont activate on classname switch

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm having and issue with my CSS, the default has class name is "qFrame". Then I have a function that changes the classname to Sheridan. In my CSS file i have a selector ".sheridan p" that is supposed to change the color of the 'p' tags but it doesn't work.

JavaScript function:

```
function sheridan()
{
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("qFrame");

    for (var i=0; i<e.length; i+=0)
       e[i].className = "sheridan";   
}
```

css file:

```
.sheridan {
    background-color: #33ABFD;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;  
}

.sheridan p {
    color: darkcyanblue;
}
```

EDIT1: http://jsbin.com/hisasorusu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: plunkr/codepen/whatever to demonstrate your issue, please!

Comment: Please put this on JSbin or fiddle with the HTML, probably the problem goes away there.

Comment: Works as expected: http://jsbin.com/gidimecici/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Here you go: http://jsbin.com/hisasorusu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Better is like `<a href="#" data-theme="sheridan">` etc. putting each theme on the same way, then _attaching_ a click handler, rather than using inline onclick, and the one-and-only click handler can get the theme name (the css class) from `data-theme`, rather than writing a separate function for each theme.

Comment: @sg.cc Don’t encourage third-party services for demonstrating code, instead encourage editing the question to include the code into the question itself and using the native stack snippet capability to make testing easier.

Answer (score 1):

The function called `sheridan()` is successfully invoked, but it is bound to the link called "Default", not "Sheridan".

Basically, you should change this:

```
Choose Theme:
<a href="#" onclick="sheridan()">Default</a> | 
<a href="#">Sheridan</a> | 
<a href="#">Candy</a>
```

into this:

```
Choose Theme:
<a href="#">Default</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="sheridan()">Sheridan</a> | 
<a href="#">Candy</a>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/bumaseseho/1/edit?html,css,js,output) is the fixed fiddle. I have added a `back2default()` function as an extra.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and then your code can look like this:

```
 $('.qFrame').addClass('sheridan');
```

It wil change your class immediately.